# how redirect page to home page if there is no error?

Tags: php, mysql

i`m trying to make a login function in login.php form. i want to redirect to index.php page if login is successful. but if there is any error in login it should redirect to same page(in this case it should be login.php). how can i implement this?

this is my code for form designing.according to this code always it is redirect to login.php .

```
<form name="login" method="POST" action="login.php">
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Login">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

this is server side code for login

```
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = mysql_query("select *from user where username='$uname'") or die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows != 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$dbuser = $row['username'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
$status = $row['status'];
}
if ($status == 0) {
?> 
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ; font-size: 17px;"  role="alert">Your account is not yet activated.Please check your email to activate account.</div>
<?php
} else if ($uname == $dbuser && $password == $dbpassword) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
?>
<?php
} else {
?> 
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ; font-size: 17px;"  role="alert">Incorrect Password.</div>
<?php
}
} else {
?> 
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ; font-size: 17px;"  role="alert">Incorrect Email.</div>
<?php
}
}
```

Comment: Answer written that should resolve the main issues..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for redirecting(Make sure you don't output/print/echo something before this).
Add this in your `else if` condition (where you are checking for valid username and password)-

```
} else if ($uname == $dbuser && $password == $dbpassword) {
//...All your session assignments
header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment.but when i use this it is showing following error
"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\koko\login.php:121) in C:\xampp\htdocs\koko\login.php on line 187"

Comment: @lahiruk93 yep. It seems like you are echoing/printing/displaying some html. Make sure you don't send anything if you are redirecting the page

Comment: In this case make sure all your form tags are below the php code and inside an else tag. If you want to redirect to another page, there's no point in outputting something right?

Comment: it means there can`t be any html,echo etc before header function called?
if so how i able to show messages to user?

Comment: @lahiruk93 If you want to redirect from server side, then no html/print/echo needs to be outputted before redirect(The user will be redirected to the home page directly if his credentials are valid, thereby he will know that his credentials are correct.).

Comment: @lahiruk93 if you want to show a screen to the user saying - "Validated. Redirecting in 5 seconds" or something like that, you need a javascript solution.

Comment: @lahiruk93 This leaves your code open to vulnerabilities and your session won't be set.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (status == 1){ //or whatever stands for logged in
    header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. when i use header function it is showing warning msg "Cannot modify header information" . why is that?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no "redirect" in your code. When you send the form, it just opens the page "login.php", that's all. If you want to add the redirect when the login is successful, just add

```
  header('Location: index.php');
```

after

```
  $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that should make your page function better and correct security issues.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["login"])) {
    $uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $query = mysql_query("select *from user where username='$uname' and password='$password' and `status` <> 0") or die(mysql_error());
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows == 0) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ; font-size: 17px;"  role="alert">Sorry the provided credentials were not valid, or you account is invalid.</div>';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
        header('Location: PAGEADDRESSHERE');
    }
}
```

Issues with your current code:
 1. User input going straight to your query. This opens you to SQL injections. Use the http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php to resolve this issue.
 2. You should check the status and the password in the same call to the DB.
 3. You shouldn't store your passwords in plain text. If a malicious user gets to your DB they will have all the users passwords. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36833/why-should-i-hash-passwords
 4. You never start your session

Now on to the redirection... you can use the PHP header function to redirect a user, http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php. The path should be absolute. If there are processes occurring after this function the exit() should be used after it to ensure all processing is stopped.

Also note the `mysql_` functions are deprecated `mysqli_` or `PDO` should be used.

Also based on your comments in the other answers here is why you are getting the warning when just adding the `header` function.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = mysql_query("select *from user where username='$uname'") or    die(mysql_error());
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows != 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$dbuser = $row['username'];
$dbpassword = $row['password'];
$status = $row['status'];
}
if ($status == 0) {
?> 
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ; font-size: 17px;"  role="alert">Your account is not yet activated.Please check your email to activate account.</div>
<?php
} else if ($uname == $dbuser && $password == $dbpassword) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $uname;
header("location: home.php");
?>
<?php
} else {
?> 
 <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ; font-size: 17px;"  role="alert">Incorrect Password.</div>
<?php
}
 } else {
  ?> 
  <div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center ;font-size:17px;"  role="alert">Incorrect Email.</div>
<?php
}
}

?>
<form name="login" method="POST" action="login.php">
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="uname" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Login">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```